# how to plot 3d graph (network) matlab?

Tags: matlab, networking, 3d, graph, plot

I want to plot a 3d graph in matlab

By graph I mean in the sense of nodes and edges. I have an adjacency matrix as well as a coordinate matrix for every node.  Eventually I would hope to colour these nodes and edges

The gplot function is only 2d.  The scatter3 function does not allow for edges.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`plot3`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/plot3.html) allows you to plot points and edges in 3D.

Answer (score 1):

It's now possible (MATLAB R2016b) to plot a node-link graph in 3d, using the graph class. Example:

```
g = graph(bucky);
plot(g, 'Layout', 'subspace3');
```

Answer (score 0):

plot3 does not plot graphs, in the sense of nodes and links. I recommend to you igraph, but it scapes of matlab.